# defining proper Macros in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a question about macros in c, Here is my code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define product(x) (x*x)

int main(){
    int i=3,j;
    j = product(i+1);
    printf("%d",j);
}
```

i guessed the answer as **16** but answer is **7**, How is it possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define product(x) (x*x*x)

int main(){
    int i=3,j;
    j = product(i+1);
    printf("%d",j);
}
```

answer of this is 10

Comment: Because it expands to `product((i+1*i+1));` which (because `*` has higher precedence than `+`) is `product(i+(1*i)+1);` Use parentheses around `x` in the macro: `#define product(x) ((x)*(x))`.

Comment: Macro arguments are not evaluated; a macro is simply a text (token) substitution.  The preprocessor will replace (expand) the source text `product(i+1)` with the text `(i+1*i+1)` before compiling.  Hence why you're being bitten by precedence issues as Johnny says above.